# Logger.info never outputs

Tags: python, logging

Why in python `logger.info("print something")` does not output. I have seen questions asked before, but solution doesnt exist. I do not want to use `logger.debug` or `logger.warning` to see text.

Simply logger.info should print the text, otherwise whats the use of this?

logging.conf file as below

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=stream

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=stream

[handler_stream]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Demo code that access logger:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("logger")
    print("print")
```

Output is only `print`, not the `logger`. So `logger.info` does not work.

Comment: Surely it depends on your log handler settings? Is it set to output at INFO level?

Comment: Your logging configuration would be helpful to help us help you...

Comment: Everything is set to INFO (root, handlers..)

Comment: Something is obviously not. You should show us the code that does the logging plus the configuration (is it in the same file, or in a config file?).

Comment: @zezollo pls see edited text. Logging.conf text.

Comment: OK, and the code loading the configuration and calling the logging function?

Comment: The code loading the configuration and calling the logging function is required. Otherwise, I don't know about `SentryLoggerRelease` and can't find any info about it. It is setup to `WARNING`. Does your logging still not work if you remove all of the `sentry` parts?

Comment: Sentry release logger also added. Refresh the link, you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you do not load your configuration file. You should add this:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('path_to_logging.conf')
```

before `logger = logging.getLogger()`

because right now you are using the default `WARNING` level.

EDIT: in order to use logging.config, you have to import it too:

```
import logging.config
```

So the complete code should be:

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('path_to_logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("logger")
    print("print")
```

The code above, with the following `logging.conf` (same as you except I removed the `sentry` parts):

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=stream

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=stream

[handler_stream]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

does work:

```
$ ./test_script3.py
2016-05-23 15:37:40,437 - root - INFO - logger
print
```

Comment: logging has no attribute config

Comment: I have got strange error: `ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'` Weird coz I have formatters in my config file.

Comment: Well, this very same code works at my place (see last edit). So I guess you do have a problem with the loading of your configuration file, somewhere. Or this is something now related to the Sentry* objects. As to the `ConfigParser` error, I don't know, it looks like you're not loading the correct file.

Comment: interesting, because when i remove sentry parts like you did, it gives me same strange error. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows (via pycharm). Is that connected?

Comment: The code you gave is python3 code, so I wrote python3 code too. This shouldn't work directly, as is, with python2.7, though at my place it does. Which error was this?

Comment: Well I can't tell more. It looks like you're not loading the file you expect (check the path). I get the same error with python2.7 if I simply remove the config file.

Comment: Forget the error part as earlier. You are right, removing sentry and loading config, lets it prints logger. However I wonder why sentry caused problem. Also why `init.py` file did not read `logging.conf` file. Will check it.

Comment: Don't know how this could change the rest of the config, but maybe it did. I don't know about sentry. I guess you have read the doc and followed their advices. https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/logging/

Comment: Well yea. I removed sentry also from the code in this question, as I do not wish to publicly show up relevant part of code.

Comment: Well, now I guess this answers the question as it is. Even if you still have to further inquire to find out what is the way the Sentry* objects work and may influence the logging configuration. But it's certainly another question.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the root logger (the one you use when you say `logger.info`) is set at a level of `WARN`.

You can either do:

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`

or `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)`